# Arch: How can I hide the pointer when I'm using my touch screen?

Tags: arch-linux, touch-screen, touch

I just installed Arch on my Lenovo Yoga 2 11" convertible laptop, and it's great so far, but when I use my touch screen, the pointer follows my touches, which it doesn't do on Ubuntu or Fedora. How can I hide the pointer when I'm using my touch screen?

Comment: I don't want to brag. But the answer to this is also (in the edit section) in the topic, I sent you about your issue a few days ago...